# Quais os nomes oficiais para "link-endereço" e "link descritivo"?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, vocabulário

Eu quando vejo um post com um link sob a forma de endereço, como

> Vê *link* em https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/link ,

vou e substituo-o por um sob a forma de descrição:

> Vê  [*link* no Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/link)

Depois, no sumário da edição, quero explicar o que fiz, e não sei o que chamar a cada um dos formatos. Tenho uma vaga ideia de ter visto usar, relacionado com isto, *inline* em inglês. Adotei a minha tática habitual: fui ver [*inline linking* na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking), para depois ver o termo usado da página correspondente em português. Mas não só não existe página correspondente em português, como não fiquei esclarecido acerca do significado exato de *inline link*: se se aplica a qualquer um dos formatos acima, se só a um, ou se a nenhum.

Eu podia inventar, por exemplo *link-endereço* e *link descritivo*. Mas já deve existir terminologia? Existem nomes usados em português para cada tipo de link? Quais são?

Comment: hiperlink e hipertexto não encaixariam?

Comment: Sumitani, *hiperlink* para 'endereço' e *hipertexto* para 'link descritivo'? Mas vocês, o pessoal da computação é que deveriam saber!

Comment: Sim, postei uma resposta mais elaborada. Engraçado que estudei isto em Comunicação e Expressão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### URL

O **link endereço** pode ser somente ***[URL](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/URL)***, um padrão de endereçamento definido no [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) (em inglês), conhecido também como **endereço web**.

Exemplos aleatórios do uso da palavra **endereço web**:

[Ajuda do Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/49942/localizacao-da-url-de-perfil-publico-do-linkedin?lang=pt)

[Ajuda do Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/329992603752372/?helpref=hc_fnav)

[Documentação da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg985381.aspx)

#### Hiperlink ou hiperligação

O que ocorre dentro de um computador quando estamos navegando na internet é que as *URL*s são realçadas automaticamente como uma característica do navegador, formando uma **[hiperligação](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hiperliga%C3%A7%C3%A3o)** ou ***hiperlink***, conhecido como simplesmente como ***link***.

#### Hipertexto e hipermídia

O **link descritivo** pode ser um texto contendo ligações para outros conteúdos por meio de **hiperligações**, assim chamamos de **[hipertexto](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hipertexto)**.

Esta resposta aqui no stackexchange é um **[hipertexto](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hipertexto)**.

Caso seu ***hiperlink*** for composto por uma imagem contendo a ligação para outro conteúdo, este pode ser chamado de **[hipermídia](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hiperm%c3%a9dia)** (pt-br) ou **[hipermédia](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hiperm%c3%a9dia)** (pt-pt).

#### Variações de hipermídia

Em comunicação, a hipermídia não se limita somente no contexto web, mas se expande para todo e qualquer dispositivo que realize a interação com o usuário por meio de ligações para outros conteúdos, como um caixa de banco, um jogo de videogame ou *smartphone*.

#### Origem

Apesar de não ser o criador da web, Ted Nelson introduziu os termos de hipermídia, hipertexto e hiperlink em uma publicação de 1965. Estas ideias derivaram de uma outra matéria chamada [As We May Think](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1945/07/as-we-may-think/303881/) de 1945 feita por Vannevar Bush, onde descrevia um sistema chamado *memex* que se assimila com as bases da web.

Comment: Excelente, muito complet. Fiquei só com duas dúvidas. *URL* pode não ser um link? Por exemplo, apenas *www . qualquercoisa . com*, um endereço que não faz nada quando se clica nele? Escreveste "Esta resposta aqui no stackexchange é um hipertexto"; a resposta toda é **um** hipertexto? ou é cada link (sob a forma de texto) que é o hipertexto?

Comment: Não sei se ele consegue não ser um link. Porque URL também virou sinônimo de link considerando a comunicação, não o termo teórico. Sim, a resposta inteira é um hipertexto. Porque a ideia seriam textos nos quais seja possível navegar entre eles de forma não linear indiferente se a URL tivesse outro padrão.

Answer (score 3):

O que se segue não é oficial, são apenas duas referências que encontrei.

---

## [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/link)

Numa página de um [curso da da Universidade do Porto](http://cmup.fc.up.pt/cmup/courses/minicursoHTML/cursoHTML-sec22.html), encontrarmos o termo **ligação por texto**.

A Universidade de Trás-os-Montes e Alto Douro mantém uma tradução das [Directivas para a acessibilidade do conteúdo da Web - 1.0](http://www.utad.pt/wai/wai-pageauth.html#link-text). Neste documento encontramos os termos **ligação descritiva** (mas parece ser num contexto ligeiramente diferente) e **texto da ligação**.

---

## https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/link

Em ambos os documentos referidos, não encontrei uma referência directa para este tipo de utilização. Diria que seria apenas **ligação** ou **endereço**.

---

## *inline linking*

Na Wikipedia, o termo refere-se à colocação de uma ligação com um texto associado, que pode corresponder ou não ao endereço da própria ligação. Por exemplo, vê em [http://pt.wikipedia.org](https://www.priberam.pt)

---

Nota: na minha opinião, no exemplo dado, trocar *em* por *no* é forçar o autor a uma dada ortografia, ou *regionalismo*, se assim se quiser chamar. Como neste exemplo: vou no/ao médico (atenção: no = em + o).

Comment: Obrigado pelas referências. Quanto à troca de *em* por *no*, eu digo *em  https : //www.seja.lá.o.que.for.com*, mas *no Priberam* (= *no dicionário Priberam*), *no. Acho que o pessoal geralmente fala assim. (O exemplo até foi inventado.) Mas se tu preferires *em Priberam* ou  *no https://www.priberam*, estás à vontade :)

Comment: @Jacinto o meu ponto não era sobre qual forma se deve usar, mas sim sobre editar isso no post de outro utilizador :)

Comment: O que vai na tua cabeça só tu sabes. O que todos podem ler ainda na tua resposta é "trocar *em* por *no* é forçar o autor [...]". De qualquer modo, isso é irrelevante para a pergunta que eu fiz. Mas no Meta discutem-se coisas deste tipo, se quiseres discutir o assunto lá.

Comment: @iled, as edições não são normativas, são apenas sugestões. Justamente por isto que existe a opção de descartá-las.

Answer (score 2):

Uma abordagem diferente: partindo da premissa de que, na língua inglesa, os dois textos são descritos por *full web address* e *link text*, respectivamente:

> The example above used an absolute URL (A **full web address**).

---

> The href attribute specifies the destination address (https://www.w3schools.com/html/) of the link.
>   The **link text** is the visible part.
>   Clicking on the **link text** will send you to the specified address.
>   <sub>Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp</sub>

A tradução mais direta para os dois tipos de link seria *endereço por extenso* e *link de texto* (ou *ligação de texto*, se você estiver se sentindo purista), também respectivamente.

Comment: Bom ponto de vista. Corrobora com a minha sugestão. Atenção: a tradução de *link text* é texto de ligação e não ligação de texto (isso seria *text link*).

Comment: @iled _texto de ligação_ é o texto que aparece para o usuário. No caso, a _ligação de texto_ seria o link em si (o "pulo" para a outra página).  Vou editar para clarificar.

Comment: A citação só refere *link text*, e a tradução de *link text* é texto de ligação.

Comment: @Ramon, também acho que *link text* é 'texto da ligação'. Parece-me que aí, eles usam simplesmente *link*, e esperam que o o link apareça sob a forma de texto e não de endereço.

Comment: @Jacinto Na verdade, link é qualquer ligação de uma página para a outra, mesmo que a ligação não seja visível ao usuário (se apertar ctrl+U, verá que há vários destas aqui mesmo, no SE). Sobre a tradução: não estou traduzindo _link text_ (que é o texto e não a ligação em si), mas a própria ligação. Confesso que tentei deixar isto mais claro mas, pelo visto, fracassei, e estou sem ideias de como melhorar a resposta.